# AngularJS hide any parent div using ng-click in a child element

Tags: angularjs, dom

I already know about ng-if and ng-show methods of showing/hiding DOM elements. In this case, however, I have about 100 div elements, each with multiple child span elements, and whenever a span is clicked, I want the parent div to hide.

Example:

```
<div>Display text
<span ng-click="hideThisDiv(this)">Option1</span>
<span ng-click="hideThisDiv(this)">Option2</span>
<span ng-click="hideThisDiv(this)">Option3</span>
</div>
```

In the function, I want to be able to do something like:

```
$scope.hideThisDiv = function(element){
element.$parent.$id.visible = false;
}
```

Using console.log(element.$parent) in this function shows, however, that there isn't a simple way to access a "visible" property of this div element. At least, not that I can see so far.

This seems like a simple concept, I'm just lacking the proper syntax or access method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code it works

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.hideParent = function (event) {
    var pEle = event.currentTarget.parentElement;
    pEle.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div>
        This is parent div click below to hide <br />
    <span ng-click="hideParent($event)">Click here to hide</span> <br />
    <span ng-click="hideParent($event)">or Here</span><br />
    <span ng-click="hideParent($event)">or Here</span>
  </div>
   
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting idea. No result, though, not even an error message.

Comment: I modified the code, now it hide the parent element

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

The better approach is to create a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and hide the parent element using jqLite.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('hideParentOnClick', function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element) {
      element.on('click', function () {
        element.parent().css({display: 'none'});
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div>
    Display text
    <span hide-parent-on-click>Option1</span>
    <span hide-parent-on-click>Option2</span>
    <span hide-parent-on-click>Option3</span>
</div>
```

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/WVMQu5YpJmTZqoKC6mOv?p=preview)

## Advantages:

- You can combine this directive with the aforementioned `ng-click` because the last one is not utilized in this method and can be freely used for any other purpose.
- Directives are intended for DOM manipulations, **not** controllers. [Read more here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).
- Better overall modularity.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to do this with jquery then use the jqLite approach with angular.element like this:

```
$scope.hideThisDiv = function(el) {
  angular.element(el.target).parent().addClass('hidden');
};
```

Then pass in the event like this:

```
<span ng-click="hideThisDiv($event)">Option1</span>
```

The add this to your css

```
.hidden {
  display:none
}
```